# How to i make to boxes inline with each other. One is under the other?

Tags: css

The code is exactly the same but it just isnt inline with the box above it.

Thanks in advance.

CSS

```
#menu {
margin-top:75px;
min-width:19px;
max-width:1920px;
height:40px;
background-color:#0F0;
border:4px groove #F00;

}
#header {
margin-top:50px;
max-width:1920px;
height:70px;
background-color:#000;
border:4px groove #F00;
```

Comment: Is this what you ask? How do I align several display:block elements in the same line? (Like divs)

Comment: You have used the word "to" to times in the title, which is to to many times... understand? no, I didn't think so

Comment: Yes that is what i mean Itay Moav -Malimovka

Comment: Where is your HTML? please post a full example that will replicate the issue. a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be useful

Answer (score 0):

If those are `div` or other block elements, you could use the CSS-attribute `float`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have part of the answer you are looking for already in your question.

If you have a block-element (or any other non-inline-element) and want it to behave like it is inline you can do so by setting the `display`-property:

`display: inline;`